# Uploading Attachment and items in Sharepoint Library in SPFX

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, spfx, spfx-webparts, pnpjs

Here is the function to upload attachments and items in the SharePoint library through React-js in SPFX.

Used PnP JS library for attachments uploading and items insertion in the SharePoint library.

I have used two api call in my function for attachment with item upload:

```
 private uploadFileFromControl():Promise<any> {
return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
 
//Get the file from File DOM
var files = this._input.files;
var file = files[0];

//Upload a file to the SharePoint Library
var url = this.props.context.pageContext.web.serverRelativeUrl;
console.log(this.props.title)
var selectedlist = this.props.description

var selectedfolder = this.props.title
if (selectedfolder == undefined) {
  var newurl = url + "/" + selectedlist
}
else {
  var newurl = url + "/" + selectedlist + "/" + selectedfolder
}
pnp.sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(newurl)

  .files.add(file.name, file, true,)
  .then((data) => {
    alert("File uploaded sucessfully");


  })
  .then(()=>{
  pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("EMSDocuments").items.add({
  DocType: 'docType'
  }).then(r => {
  alert("success");
  })
   })
  .catch((error) => {
    alert(error);
  });
})
}
```

Attachment upload is successful but don't know the way to insert item in the SharePoint library through PnP JS Library.

I am able to insert item in the SharePoint list through 2nd API call but getting an error when inserting in SharePoint library.

Comment: Are you trying to update the properties/metadata of same file you are uploading in first call? or creating 2nd item in another list/library?

Comment: Yes i am creating 2nd call to insert item in particular column in SharePoint library,

Comment: OK. But, are you trying to add value for column against the same file you uploaded in first call.. (in same document library)?

Comment: Yes, right i was trying to achieve that only  but for now i was to trying to add item in a specific library to check the api call 
if it  is working properly or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to upload a file to SharePoint library & update it's item properties, use below code:

```
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp";

sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(newurl).files.add(file.name, file, true).then(f => {

    f.file.getItem().then(item => {

        item.update({
            Title: "A Title",
            OtherField: "My Other Value"
        });
    });
});
```

**Source**: [@pnp/sp/files - Setting Associated Item Values](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/v1/sp/docs/files/#setting-associated-item-values)

Comment: Hi @Abhishek, did you try this? Is it working for you?

Comment: Yes @Ganesh , It worked Thanks a lot

Comment: okay sure but i had already upvoted Thanks